# Multiple Saves in NHibernate (2.1)

Tags: c#, nhibernate

How can I save a collection of objects in NHibernate?
I'm migration from SubSonic (I don't like SubSonic 3 version and SubSonic 2 is dead...) and this used to be a simple operation...

There is a way to map a collection(without associations) to complete this task?

My actual code is:

```
using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession())
{
    using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        foreach (var player in players)
        {
             session.Save(player);
             transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to commit the transaction outside of your loop. The goal of a transaction is to essentially batch multiple operations to the database in 1 call. Here's the edited version:

```
using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession())
{
    using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        foreach (var player in players)
        {
            session.Save(player);
        }
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried this, but got this exception:

a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: 0, of entity: TabelaDigitalCL.Player

I solve this using a session.Flush() after every save(player)...
But I think doing a Flush every time don't seems right (not performatic).

Any tip?
Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Solved. I set the id of the object, even when the related table's id  is set as auto-increment.
This would throw a exception ins SubSonic, but works just fine for NHibernate.

But thanks anyway zowens.